# Total angular momentum J=L+S eigenstates parity

Tags: quantum-spin

For an angular momentum eigenstate $|l,m\rangle$ Sakurai says that

$$ |l,m\rangle = (-1)^l |l,m \rangle $$

I have a problem in which I have $ J = L + S $ and I want to apply the previous formula. I am dealing with a spin 1/2 particle so I have states like $|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ (coupled base state). If I use the formula such a state will have an imaginary parity... What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Particle physics: Why is J^P called spin parity if J is the total angular momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/175501/particle-physics-why-is-jp-called-spin-parity-if-j-is-the-total-angular-moment)